# Codeigniter curly quotes (despite UTF-8 collation)

Tags: php, codeigniter, utf-8, quotes

I'm using a simple form to write string to database, but the curly quotes (on retrieval) are being displayed as special characters.

So far I have tried changing the table collation to UTF-8 as well as using the CodeIgniter Typography class:

```
 1. alter table test.vocab convert to character set utf8 collate
    utf8_unicode_ci;
 2. $this->load->library('typography'); 
    $data['item'] = $this->typography->auto_typography($data['item'], FALSE);
```

This hasn't helped, though. Here's what the output looks like:

[image]

If needed I'll post more code. Please help.

Comment: Sounds like it's not your database. Have you set the pages charset to utf-8 in your html files header? `<meta charset="utf-8" />` . The other thing that could be a problem is your locale. Try using [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you everyone, but it seems like what I needed was the `mb_convert_encoding()` function:

```
$i['item'] = mb_convert_encoding($i['item'], 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
```

Many thanks for taking out the time for commenting or answering.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a migrated DB. Turned out I needed to convert  'UTF-8' to 'Windows-1252'.

I found out by running the code below and checking which combination looked right:

```
$html = 'Your HTML here';


$charsets = array(  
    "UTF-8", 
    "ASCII", 
    "Windows-1252", 
    "ISO-8859-15", 
    "ISO-8859-1", 
    "ISO-8859-6", 
    "CP1256"
    ); 


 foreach ($charsets as $ch1) { 
      foreach ($charsets as $ch2){ 
       echo "<h1>Combination $ch1 to $ch2 produces: </h1>".iconv($ch1, $ch2, $html); 
    } 
}
```